# How do I recreate the lines and labels as seen in this image?

Tags: plotting, special-functions

[image]

How do I recreate the light gray lines and labels pointing to the zeros of this function?

I have no prior experience using Mathematica, so please include all code or resources.

I have the list of zeros here:

```
N[Table[Im[ZetaZero[k]], {k, 1, 29}], 10]
```